# hosted service to call a webpage at a scheduled time?

Tags: service

I am looking for a hosted service to call certain webpages at a certain time. I am looking for a company that offers this service, anyone know of such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try [Web Based Cron](http://webbasedcron.com/)